# Why Models aren't loaded yet?

Tags: python, django

I'm traying to do makemigrations and I have the error:

```
core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet
```

In the line:

```
def get_facultad_defecto():
```

I'm trying to do something like this, assigning some defaults values and set it on_delete() action in ForeingKey field:

```
ID_POR_DEFECTO = 1

def get_user_defecto():
    """ obtener o crear una User por defecto """
    return User.objects.get_or_create(username="nouser")[0]

def get_sede_defecto():
    """ obtener o crear una Sede por defecto """
    return Sede.objects.get_or_create(nombre="NO SEDE")[0]

class Sede(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'sede'
        verbose_name_plural = 'sedes'

def get_facultad_defecto():
    """ obtener o crear una Facultad por defecto """
    return Facultad.objects.get_or_create(sede=ID_POR_DEFECTO, codigo="NO CODIGO", nombre="NO FACULTAD")[0]

class Facultad(models.Model):
    sede = models.ForeignKey(Sede, default=get_sede_defecto(), on_delete=models.SET(get_sede_defecto()))
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250) 
    decano = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'facultad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'facultades'
```

In settings:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'res_estudiantil',
]
```

Thanks for your attention.